# Should I and how to transitionToRoute in a promise callback

Tags: javascript, ember.js, callback, promise, ic-ajax

In an Ember controller, I want to call my API to create a user and on success, transitionToRoute. This is what I currently want to work:

```
import ajax from "ic-ajax";
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {  
    createAndLoginUser: function() {
      var user = { "user": this.getProperties("email", "name") };
      ajax({ url: "api/users", type: "POST", data: user })
        .then(transitionToHome);
    }   
  }
});

var transitionToHome = function() {
  this.transitionToRoute("home")
}
```

But when I place a `debugger` in the method, `this` is no longer the controller object and is out of scope to call `transitionToRoute`.

I've only ever written hacky javascript, but I'm trying to learn core concepts and some frameworks. Is this the right way to use a promise? And is this the right place in Ember to put a transition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with Ember or transitions; it's all about `this` handling. The simplest solution is just

```
.then(transitionToHome.bind(this));
```

#### Putting transition method inside the controller

You could also consider putting `transitionToHome` inside the controller as a method. Then, you could call it as in the following:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  transitionToHome: function() { this.transitionToRoute("home"); },

  actions: {  
    createAndLoginUser: function() {
      var self = this;
      var user = { "user": this.getProperties("email", "name") };
      ajax({ url: "api/users", type: "POST", data: user })
        .then(function() { self.transitionToHome(); });
    }   
  }

});
```

This might be a simpler approach which is more readable and doesn't require reasoning about `this` and using `bind` (but does require using `self`).

#### Moving the transition to the route?

Outside the scope of your question, but some would say that route-related logic (including transitioning) logically belongs in the route, not the controller. If you agree, you could refactor the above to do a `send`

```
createAndLoginUser: function() {
  var user = { "user": this.getProperties("email", "name") };
  var self = this;
  ajax({ url: "api/users", type: "POST", data: user })
    .then(function() { self.send("goHome"); });
  }
}
```

and then implement the `goHome` action in your route. Or, you could implement `goHome` in a higher-level route, even the application route, thus making it available from any controller or lower-level route.

#### Moving the AJAX logic to a service?

Others might say that the ajax logic does not really belong here in the controller, and should rightfully be in a services layer, so

```
// services/user.js
export function createUser(data) {
  return ajax({ url: "api/users", type: "POST", data: { user: data } });
}

// controller
import { createUser } from 'app/services/user';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  createAndLoginUser: function() {
    var data = this.getProperties("email", "name"));
    var self = this;
    createUser(data) . then(function() { self.send("goHome"); });
  }
};
```

Using ES6 syntax, we can avoid the `self`, simplifying a bit in the process:

```
  createAndLoginUser: function() {
    var data   = this.getProperties("email", "name"));
    var goHome = () => this.send("goHome");

    createUser(data) . then(goHome);
  }
```

Now this code is starting to look more semantic and readable.

Comment: Alternatively, when I try to add it as a controller method, I receive the same `Cannot read property 'transitionToHome' of undefined`

`transitionToHome: function() { this.transitionToRoute("home") },`

EDIT: Just added my controller method code.

Comment: Sorry, there was a this/self problem now fixed.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback too! I'm definitely going to try those refactors, I've been struggling a bit with the Ember documentation.

Comment: Got these refactors working, the code looks great! A couple of things I encountered making them: 1) `createUser` import had to be `../services/user`? 2) the `createUser` method was apart of the class `user` from the import? Other than that, thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. You can import using either a relative or absolute path. The former would be `from '../services/user'`, the latter would be `from '*appname*/services/user'`, replacing `appname` with the actual name of your application, and assuming `services` is at the top of your tree. I prefer the latter in this case. Wrt your second point, my mistake, The import should have been `import {createUser} from `...'`.

Comment: We're now completely working like a charm, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to simply use ES6 arrow syntax to maintain the context of `this`:

```
import ajax from "ic-ajax";
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {  
    createAndLoginUser() {
      let user = { "user": this.getProperties("email", "name") };
      ajax({ url: "api/users", type: "POST", data: user })
        .then(() => {
          this.transitionToRoute("home");
        });
    }   
  }
});
```